# My installer left a 5/8" ridge just above my shower. What is the best fix?

Tags: drywall, shower, patching-drywall

I paid someone to install tile in a walk in shower, but on the outside, he left a 5/8" or so overlap at the top left (see pics). I want him to make this seamless, but I'm not sure the best way to do that (and I want to know if there are any "easy" answers that he might suggest that are just bad ideas and that I should not accept?

The right top is better, but still not exactly lined up.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Top looking down][image: Inside View][image: Front View]

Comment: Where's the tile in the first pic?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, this was a job done by someone with questionable skills, a lack of pride in their work , or both.

The sill used on the side, was a poor choice and should have been cut down to the proper width to match the thickness of the wall.  A better solution would have been metal edge, such as schluter jolly and tile.

If it were my home, I would demand the sill be removed along with the drywall used to cover the edge. Then the sides done in tile and aluminium edge.  Of course the drywall be repaired as well.

An alternative could be adding drywall and finishing the wall outside the shower up to the ceiling.